# не работает PDO rowCount()

Tags: php

Есть у меня генерация токена плюс проверка на уникальность ( запрос к БД "Есть ли уже юзер с таким токеном?" ). При попытке запустить скрипт мне выдает пустоту. Возвращается ничего. Просто не работает. При чём не работает не только rowCount, а и fetchAll ( я думал с помощью него сделать проверку, раз уж rowCount не работает ). В чем может быть причина?
Код:

```php
$nuwRows = 1;

while( $numRows == 1 ) {

    $num = random_int( 8, 16 );
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes($num));

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `token` = :token LIMIT 1");

    $query->execute(array( 'token' => $token ));

    $numRows = $query->rowCount();

}

exit( $token );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот так: // ошибка в названии переменной поставь в условии nuwRows вместо numRows

```
$nuwRows = 1;
while ( $nuwRows == 1 ) {

    $num = random_int( 8, 16 );
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes($num));
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `token` = :token LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute(array( 'token' => $token ));
    $numRows = $query->rowCount();

}

exit( $token );
```

Comment: Не работает. Как была пустота, так и осталась (Ну, разве что теперь не "", а NULL)

Comment: Напиши сюда, что происходит внутри метода:
$db->prepare()

Comment: а еще попробуй выполнить var_dump(bin2hex(random_bytes($num)))

и значение которое он вернет, посмотри есть ли оно в БД в таблице users, с таким токеном

Comment: var_dump($query == "NULL") - дамп препейра.дамп bin2hex отображает токен, работает корректно. Похоже, что var_dump не сработал. У меня ощущение что я с while натупил как то..

Comment: var_dump($token) - какое значение показывает?

Comment: Если вынести генерацию token за пределы while, то токен. Если не выносить - null

Comment: while на if перепиши и попробуй сделать var_dump($token)

Comment: Всё тот же NULL. А вот если убрать вообще while(или if) , то вылезает что-то такое: object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(55) "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `token` = :token LIMIT 1"
}
b0f5f7c91d22d552f567ad46adf0

Comment: Не убирая if попробуй после
$token =. .... ;

написать: 
var_dump($token);
die();

Что он покажет?

Comment: null показывает. при чем я дописал в конце вместо exit($token) - exit('123')... и о магия, вывелось 123...

Comment: Попробуй вот так:
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

$nuwRows = 1;
if ( $numRows == 1 ) {

    $num = random_int( 8, 16 );
    var_dump($num);

}

Что он покажет?

Comment: ```<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: numRows in <b>D:\OSPanel\domains\mysite.loc\guest\guest_handler.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: token in <b>D:\OSPanel\domains\mysite.loc\guest\guest_handler.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />```

Comment: СМОТРИ!

$nuwRows  и $numRows = разные!!!!

Comment: как. же. все. глупо. ну блин, с таким ошибиться xDD. Поменял nuW на nuM - всё прекрасно работает. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Поэтому и не работает условие,
так как ты одной переменной даешь значение 1, а на условие проверяешь другую переменную, в этом проблема